# Image doesn't show when getting from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I read image url from server but it's name is the same for all users. 
ex. http://localhost:1337/data/performer/:perfID/avatar/avatar.jpg

When I want to show the image I set the image source to the url above but the image doesn't show up until I click somewhere in the page. I guess the problem is with the angular digest, but I tried with $scope.$apply() and $scope.$digest() but it doesn't help.

I set the url like this.

```
$scope.imageSource = CONSTS.userAvatar.replace('$1', $scope.userID) + "?n=" + Math.random();
```

Аny suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
<img id="avatarImage" ng-src="{{imageSource}}" ng-mouseover="showDelete=true;" onerror="angular.element(document.getElementById('avatarImage')).scope().avatarDoesntExist()" onload="angular.element(document.getElementById('avatarImage')).scope().avatarExist()"  ng-mouseleave="showDelete=false;" class="thumbnail" style='margin-right: 7px;margin-top: 7px;margin-bottom: 7px;width: 100%;'/>
```

I have two methods ("onload"/"onerror") because there can be avatar image in the folder or not. If there isn't any image in the avatar folder I show box with Browse button and if user has avatar image I show box with the image and hide the box with browse button.

Comment: Add code to your post to show how you are setting the `imageSource` to your image.  Hopefully you are using `ng-src`?

Comment: I tried with ng-src but it doesn't work

Comment: When do you set the image source?  You said "when I want to show the image", does that mean it's some sort of event that you are calling to set it?  Could you throw your markup code in here?

Comment: See the edited post. I posted the image html tag.